# Is it possible to have Windows Authentication and JWT in the same application in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, api, entity-framework-core

I have a application working fine with Windows Authentication in IIS Server. Only some Active Directory users have access to the application. I want to have a option where a person without AD user can access the application with JWT and have HttpContext.User setted and roles too.

Example:

1. Person without AD user open the application in a computer with autologin (sysexample).
2. Application detect that the sysexample user it's not allowed in the application and redirect to the login page.
3. User logs in with non-AD user and the HttpContext.User is changed to the logged and not sysexample.

Is something like that possible?